# Describing the annihilator

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I am trying to describe the following:

Say we have a space $V$, where $V = R^3$, then we also have the annihilator of the span:

$(span(ε^2 + ε^3))^o$ of this space $V$.

How would someone describe the annihilator of this span?

What is meant by this question? I know that the annihilator set are all the functions of the set leading to the zero outcome. I don't understand how the zero outcome would be related to the span. Overall, the span is basically the basis of the vector space, so how can there be an annihilator of the span?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $R = \mathbb R$? What are $\varepsilon^2$ and $\varepsilon^3$ supposed to be? "... the span is basically the basis of the vector space, so..." what?!

Comment: My advice: Review the material and rephrase the question in your own words - explaining the definitions that need to be explained. I do not think you have properly understood what is going on here (you certainly haven't communicated it in a way that can be understood!). Reviewing the material so you understand what is being asked is always the first step to dealing with a problem. If you dump a problem you don't understand here or elsewhere any solution somebody might post will also be of minimal value to you!